# MongoDB: How to find only customers ordered?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have 2 collection Customers and Order with sample data as below

```
**Customers**
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "John", "sex" : "male" }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "Sara", "sex" : "female"}
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "Jack", "sex" : "male"}
{ "_id" : 4, "name" : "David", "sex" : "male"}

**Orders**
{ "_id" : 1, customerId: 1 }
{ "_id" : 2, customerId: 1 }
{ "_id" : 3, customerId: 2 }
```

I would like:
- Count total number only customers that ordered
- Count total male or femal

Using mongo aggregate

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried ? Both foreign key and primary key needs to be of same type. Cant be string & number.

Comment: I have try like this:

db.customers.aggregate([{$lookup: {from: "orders", localField: "_id", foreignField: "customerId", as: "orders_customer"}}}])

Comment: Yes, I modified the question. customerId is number.

The output of above aggregate show all customers, I don't know how to remove customers that do not order

{"_id": 1, "name": "John", "sex": "male", "orders_customer": [{"_id": 1, "customerId": 1}, {"_id": 2, "customerId": 2}]}
{"_id": 2, "name": "Sara", "sex": "female", "orders_customer": [{"_id": 3, "customerId": 2}]}
{"_id": 3, "name": "Jack", "sex": "male", "orders_customer": []}
{"_id": 4, "name": "David", "sex": "male", "orders_customer": []}

Comment: Add `{$match:{order_customer:{$ne:[]}}`} after lookup to filter customers with non empty order and $group stage with $sum for total count of customers who ordered and $sum with $cond for each male and female count. Something  like `{$group:{     _id:null       count:{$sum:1},      male:{$sum:{$cond:[{$eq:["$sex", "male"]}, 1, 0]}}     }   }`

Comment: Finally, it works. Thank you Veeram!